# how can i access the proprety in the Component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to get the prop with name number in the Marker component when I press on the component

I have used an array to push my components in

```
markers = []
this.markers.push(<Marker 
                      onPress={()=> this._shapeFocused(event) }  
                      coordinate={latLng} data={this.state.markerNumber} 
                      key={"MN-" + this.state.markerNumber}
                      number={"5"}
                      //value={"marker"}
                    ></Marker>)
```

after the components are pushed. on pressing one of them I want to get their number prop to push it to the global store
**I have tried event.target.prop but it doesn't work**

```
  _shapeFocused(e) {
   //get the key of the component
  let key = e.target.number;
   // send the component key to the global state:
  let action = { type: "ShapeFocused", value: key}
  this.props.dispatch(action)
 }
```

Comment: You need to pass `event` in `_shapedFocused` function like `onPress={(event)=> this._shapeFocused(event) } `

Comment: thank you. but it doesn't work. I meant in my question if there is a way to **access** the clicked component props and get the value of prop called "number"